# When multithreading, some threads hang for a few minutes

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application with multiple threads in C#, and some threads hang for a long time (multiple minutes). Example: I create 50 threads...All the threads have same function, but some threads will stop and no do processing for a few minutes, than run again. What possible causes might there be for this? Is it because the processor has limited threads? This seems odd, becaust it is waiting too long when the processor shows it is just using few % of capacity, i.e. is not overloaded.

Here is some code I used to create multiple threads:

```
clsCreateThread clsCreateThread = new clsCreateThread(dataA,dataB,dataC);
arrayThreads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clsCreateThread.StartNewThread));
arrayThreads[i].Start();
```

Comment: What code is executed in thread?

Comment: Are you sure you call Thread.Sleep in your thread methods to let the scheduler switch your threads?

Comment: By default your application won't use more than single core of multi-core CPU, so you won't achieve 100% CPU  load